# GulpJS: usemin not updating build html

Tags: html, hyperlink, gulp

Here is the 'usemin' section of the gulpfile.js

```
// usemin Task
gulp.task('usemin', function() {
  gulp.src('./*.html')
    .pipe(usemin({
      css: [minifyCss(), 'concat'],
      html: [minifyHtml({empty: true})],
      js: [uglify(), rev()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

When I run 'gulp' it generates all the files I need in the build folder but does not update the links in the index.html file with the newly generated files (minified and concatenated).

Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: found a solution yet?

Comment: No I have stilll not been able to fix this.